# Конвертер .svg в <svg>

Tags: html, svg

А существует ли конвертер из формата .svg в код?

```
<svg>
   <path/>
</svg>
```

Comment: А открыть в редакторе .svg и посмотреть <svg> не можете?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko В редакторе открывается .svg без <path>. А мне нужен именно он.

Comment: так может быть его и нет)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko а я спрашивал конкретно про path.

Comment: SVG может быть без path. И в каком редакторы вы его открывали?

Comment: И может вы лучше расскажете что за задачу пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Вопрос не потерял актуальность за сроком давности? А что же вы всё таки имели ввиду, просто интересно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT уже неактуально. Я плохо ориентировался тогда в svg :)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin ОК. Задайте тогда, что-нибудь про SVG актуальное. Сейчас много ребят собралось с хорошими знаниями SVG Обязательно ответят, если конечно смогут. Вопросы разные бывают

Answer (score 1):

Конвертер не нужен, так как svg-файл состоит из единственного тега `<svg>`, в таком виде, что он без изменений может быть вставлен в HTML.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct

> An SVG document fragment consists of any number of SVG elements contained within an ‘svg’ element.
>
> (...)
>
> An SVG document fragment can stand by itself as a self-contained file or resource, in which case the SVG document fragment is an SVG document, or it can be embedded inline as a fragment within a parent HTML or XML document.

Единственное что можно сделать, это вырезать заголовок XML-документа (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`) или директиву DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC ...>`), если они содержатся в файле. Но и это необязательно, так как браузеры имеют свойство пропускать неизвестные теги.